# WordPress лишние посты

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cms

При помощи плагина Option Tree сделал настройку для вывода определенных рубрик на главной странице.

```
<?php get_header();
$a = 5; ?>
<div class="content content-pos">

    <div class="row portfolio ">
        <?php
        $str_cat = '';

        if (!empty(ot_get_option('my_category'))) {
//            echo '1';
            /* get the slider array */
            $slides = ot_get_option('my_category', array());
            if (!empty($slides)) {
                foreach ($slides as $slide) {
                    $str_cat = $str_cat . $slide['category_ch'] . ',';

                }
            }

        }

        $args = array(
            'cat' => $str_cat
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query->have_posts()):

            //        для проверки clearfix
            $clear_md = 0;
            $clear_sm = 0;
            ?>

            <?php while ($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();

            //считаем clearfix
            $clear_md++;
            $clear_sm++;

            ?>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nop">
                <div class="content__block content__block-pos z-depth-1">
                    <div class="content__top">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                           class="content__img content__img-pos"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>

                        <h3 class="content__title content__title-pos"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class=""
                                                                         title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="content__article content__article-pos"><?php the_excerpt() ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__bottom">

                        <div class="divider"></div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="content__read waves-effect content__read-pos"><span> Read
                    more</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            //        вставляем clearfix
            if ($clear_md % 3 == 0) {
                echo ' <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>';
            }
            if ($clear_md % 2 == 0) {
                echo ' <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
            }
            ?>

            <?php
            $start_row++;
        endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Создал отдельно файл с category.php, что бы index.php не мешал выводу постов в страница-рубриках. Страницы-рубрики работают хорошо. Но на главной странице появляется пагинация!!! На главной странице выводится всего 4-ре поста (из 6 дозволенных), и почему то появляется пагинация на 2-ю страницу, где те же 4 поста. Почему так произошло?

Comment: js снипеты для js, `{}` вот это для кода.

Comment: Наверняка функция `pagination()` работает для главного запроса ("main loop"). Ваши посты выводятся специальным (не главным) запросом, и о них эта функция не знает, зато знает про посты, которые по-умолчанию выводятся на главной. Найдите где именно определена эта функция и добавьте ее в текст вопроса, а там видно будет

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо большое, ваш ответ правильный, поменял функцию пагинации всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что пагинация появляется из-за вот этого участка кода

```
<div class="content">
    <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

Попробуйте его удалить.

Comment: Пагинация  должна быть, и работать тогда,  когда это необходимо. Сейчас необходимости нет.

Comment: тогда логично было бы привести код функции, которая отвечает за работу пагинации, телепаты сюда заходят редко

Comment: Ну да, работы и так хватает :)

Answer (score 1):

Доброго вечера!
Можно попробовать такое:

Замените ваш код:

```
<div class="content">
  <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

На такую конструкцию:

```
<div class="content">
  <?php if(!is_home()) { pagination(); } ?>
</div>
```

is_home() - проверяет что за страница выводится. [Вот тут док](http://wp-kama.ru/function/is_home).

Comment: Спасибо,  но мне не подойдет,  тк я не говорю что там будет только 4 запись,  может быть и 10-20, настройку я сделал для пользователя что бы ему было удобнее выводить на главной странице записи которые он хочет.  То есть пагинация нужна, но только тогда когда она требуется.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вы пытаетесь переопределить количество постов на главной странице, это не рекомендуется делать.

Согласно справке Wordpress, правильно делать через "Параметры"->"Чтение"->"На страницах блога отображать не более".

Проверьте, сколько у вас там установлено постов к выводу.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ в следующем:
Если вы меняете запрос для цикла вывода постов на какой-то странице, то нужно менять и запрос на вывод пагинации для той же страницы!